# call "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" in "applicationDidBecomeActive"

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, multitasking

Is it bad practice to call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`?  I was calling it in `applicationDidFinishLoading`, but with multitasking, the registration was not happening for days to weeks for some users.

I'd like to call the registration more often, but don't want to call it this often if it's bad practice.

Answer (score 19):

It is not bad practice.

In fact Apple documentation says this: [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2)

> If your application has previously registered, calling
>   `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` results in iOS passing the device
>   token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional
>   overhead.

Comment: Updated link to [Local and Remote Notifications Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 5):

**Device tokens can change.**

> Your app needs to reregister every time it is launched in iOS by
>   calling the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method of
>   `UIApplication`.

Based on [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2)

Comment: Updated link to [Local and Remote Notifications Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1)